# Python pandas dataframe: find max for each unique values of an another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a large dataframe (from 500k to 1M rows) which contains for example these 3 numeric columns: ID, A, B

I want to filter the results in order to obtain a table like the one in the image below, where, for each unique value of column id, i have the maximum and minimum value of A and B.
How can i do?

EDIT: i have updated the image below in order to be more clear: when i get the max or min from a column i need to get also the data associated to it of the others columns

[image]

Comment: what do you do if several rows have the same min or max value/

Comment: good question by @Boud.  It didn't matter in my first answer (which interpreted the question incorrectly).  My current answer is using `idxmax/min` which will take the first row in the event of ties.  I think this becomes a much harder question without some assumption like that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sample data (note that you posted an image which can't be used by potential answerers without retyping, so I'm making a simple example in its place):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({ 'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'a':range(8), 'b':range(8,0,-1) })
```

The key to this is just using `idxmax` and `idxmin` and then futzing with the indexes so that you can merge things in a readable way.  Here's the whole answer and you may wish to examine intermediate dataframes to see how this is working.

```
df_max = df.groupby('id').idxmax()
df_max['type'] = 'max'
df_min = df.groupby('id').idxmin()
df_min['type'] = 'min'

df2 = df_max.append(df_min).set_index('type',append=True).stack().rename('index')

df3 = pd.concat([ df2.reset_index().drop('id',axis=1).set_index('index'), 
                  df.loc[df2.values] ], axis=1 )

df3.set_index(['id','level_2','type']).sort_index()

                 a  b
id level_2 type      
1  a       max   3  5
           min   0  8
   b       max   0  8
           min   3  5
2  a       max   7  1
           min   4  4
   b       max   4  4
           min   7  1
```

Note in particular that df2 looks like this:

```
id  type   
1   max   a    3
          b    0
2   max   a    7
          b    4
1   min   a    0
          b    3
2   min   a    4
          b    7
```

The last column there holds the index values in `df` that were derived with `idxmax` & `idxmin`.  So basically all the information you need is in `df2`.  The rest of it is just a matter of merging back with `df` and making it more readable.

Comment: many thanks for your response. This is almost what i need. I have updated the question in order to be more clear

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking to get min and max values of a specific column where there is a unique ID, this is how I modified the above code:

```
df_maxA = df.groupby('id').max()['A']
df_maxA['type'] = 'max'
df_minA = df.groupby('id').max()['A']
df_minA['type'] = 'min'

df_maxB = df.groupby('id').max()['B']
df_maxB['type'] = 'max'
df_minB = df.groupby('id').max()['B']
df_minB['type'] = 'min'
```

Then you can merge these together to create a single dataframe.